# in Bash you can set -x to enable debugging, is there any way to know if that has been set or not from within the script?

Tags: bash, debugging, set

When making complex bash scripts, I will often use the command:

```sh
set -x
```

to enable me to debug the script if it is not behaving.

However I have some UI functions that generate a LOT of garbage in debug mode, so I would like to wrap them in a conditional along the lines of:

```
ui~title(){
    DEBUG_MODE=0
    if [ set -x is enabled ] # this is the bit I don't know how to do
    then
        # disable debugging mode for this function as it is not required and generates a lot of noise
        set +x
        DEBUG_MODE=1
    fi

    # my UI code goes here

    if [ "1" == "$DEBUG_MODE" ]
    then
        # re enable debugging mode here
        set -x
    fi
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to know if debug mode is enabled or not.

I'm assuming it is possible, I just can't seem to find it despite lots of searching.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: two great answers, cheers!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the following:

```
if [[ "$-" == *x* ]]; then
  echo "is set"
else
  echo "is not set"
fi
```

From [3.2.5. Special parameters](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_05):

> A hyphen expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set built-in command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i).

Comment: `[ ${-/x/} != $- ]` is another way for the same result: If removing the x from $- (`${-/x/}`) is different from the original `$-`, it means that the x was enabled.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ [ -o xtrace ] ; echo $?
1
$ set -x
++ ...
$ [ -o xtrace ] ; echo $?
+ '[' -o xtrace ']'
+ echo 0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, here are the two re-usable functions:

```sh
is_shell_attribute_set() { # attribute, like "x"
  case "$-" in
    *"$1"*) return 0 ;;
    *)    return 1 ;;
  esac
}


is_shell_option_set() { # option, like "pipefail"
  case "$(set -o | grep "$1")" in
    *on) return 0 ;;
    *)   return 1 ;;
  esac
}
```

Usage example:

```sh
set -x
if is_shell_attribute_set e; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # yes

set +x
if is_shell_attribute_set e; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # no

set -o pipefail
if is_shell_option_set pipefail; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # no

set +o pipefail
if is_shell_option_set pipefail; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # no
```